# Concat two variable values with space in Lua

Tags: string, lua, string-concatenation

I have a string I am trying to build out of a variable containing strings and a space and an another string(integer.)  The string needs to consist of index numbers based on the number of elements in a table called "master_table" The first time through the variable "indexes_to_process" is nil.  I am trying to use the stanza below to set it.  However, it still contains a nil value even through x is set correctly.  I am sure this is some syntax gotcha that I am drawing a blank on.  I've tried several alterations to this and nothing works.  Would appreciate any suggestions.  The goal is to have a variable that contains the following:

"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15"  and so on.  I am doing this so I can have a variable control loop of thousands to millions of index numbers. . . .this was my solution to address slow table processing after 100K elements.   Ie., I want to be able to add index numbers to the variable "indexes_to_process" so that loop will hit this element.  This save me processing empty elements in the table because the processing through all table elements takes too long after I get into the 100K range and I have maybe 10K elements that need to be processed.

Thanks in Advance!

```
if indexes_to_process == nil then
                            for x = 1,table.maxn(master_table) do
                                print ("x:"..x)                         --uncomment for debug
                                indexes_to_process = (indexes_to_process," ",x)
                                print ("indexes to process",indexes_to_process)         --uncomment for debug
                            end
end
```

Comment: You dont get an error on this line? `indexes_to_process = (indexes_to_process," ",x)` that line should throw an error, i believe you want to use `..` not `,` if i understand your intent properly.

Comment: I don't get an error straight away; actually I don't want to use the ".." because that does not work with nil values and the first run through, the "indexes_to_process" variable will be nil.  It could be nil in other iterations as well.  

I know I have done this before but I've looked and looked at this and never get it right.

Comment: Here is the output form the above loop.  As you can see it works, but my variable ends up nil.  

Sample Output:

indexes to process      nil
x:3333
indexes to process      nil
x:3334
indexes to process      nil
x:3335
indexes to process      nil
x:3336

Comment: what version of lua or lua environment are you working in? `indexes_to_process = (indexes_to_process," ",x)` this should not work because you are not assigning any value to `indexes_to_process ` based on how that line is written it should give an error. if you have to handle when your `indexes_to_process` is `nil` you can do `indexes_to_process = (indexes_to_process or "someDefaultString") .. " " .. x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are 2 examples:

```
local master_table = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
local indexes_to_process

-- first
indexes_to_process = table.concat(master_table," ")
print(indexes_to_process)

-- second
indexes_to_process = nil
local temp = {}
for k,v in ipairs(master_table) do
   temp[#temp+1] = v .." "
end
indexes_to_process = table.concat(temp)
print(indexes_to_process)
```

in any case, never glue strings inside a large loop, memory consumption and performance drops, like:

```
indexes_to_process = indexes_to_process.. " "..x   -- bad idea
```

PS: if you think that the value `x` can be nil, use:

```
x = (x or "") .. "text"
```

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I'm back to the drawing board.  I need a much quicker way to handle this---looping through every table element doesn't work when I may have millions and more than half will be nil.

Comment: use `temp[#temp+1] = (v or '') .." "` as i showed in p.s.